# Visual Studio : C++ : How I can share a variable across all my forms?

Tags: c++, string, forms, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

First of all, I am using Visual Studio 2010 and I'm trying to write in C++. :p

Here is my question.

Let's say i define a String in Form1, in my case this:

```
String^ serverlogin="datasource=;port=;username=;password=";
```

and i want to use it across ALL my forms, what should I do?

I think that this should be defined in public but then I don't know how to access it. :/

I tried to call it in Form2 with this:

```
String^ movedvar=Form1::serverlogin;
```

but it didn't worked...

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Check this answer which explains how to declare global variables correctly: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433204/how-do-i-share-a-variable-between-source-files-in-c-with-extern-but-how

Comment: thank you for your answer! I managed to make it work with integers, but it doesn't work with system strings (String). Any ideas?

Comment: Sakis, the caret on your variable declaration might be preventing your code from working. I read a bit about it and it seems adding the ^ symbol after String turns your variable into a managed one. Try removing the caret or declaring your variable in its own class as a non-static member if you want to keep it.

Comment: I tried without the caret with no success. I'm getting crazy with this, I managed it to work with int, double and std::string but it won't work with the System String! :@

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I share a variable between source files in C? With \`extern\`, but how?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433204/how-do-i-share-a-variable-between-source-files-in-c-with-extern-but-how)